# How can I do "svn diff" side-by-side in emacs

Tags: emacs, diff

M-x vc-diff is cool. 
But not enough for me.
Is it possible to diff side-by-side in emacs like GUI diff tools ? (kdiff3, meld)

Comment: What do you mean by "not enough for me" ? Can you be more specific about the problem you have and the expected solution ?

Comment: Specifically, it is hard for me to distinguish which parts are changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use vc-ediff (bound to "E" in my config published on https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/emacs-leuven.el).

Comment: thanks. it's what I want to find. thank you fniessen.